# Amazon AWS RDS IP address

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I am migrating Windows dotnet sites to AWS.  Right now I manage which database my sites look at by modifying the Servers Host files to point to the database IP.  Is the RDS database hostname a dynamicIP anyway to ensure its static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your application should point at the hostname of the RDS instance. If you create a DNS CNAME record within your domain that points to the RDS instance you can have more flexibility for future changes.

Comment: I was using hostname productiondb that was in compiled code. Many of these apps are legacy and very difficult to recompile.  Whenever I wanted to changed databases I would just set host file setting for productionDB.  To resolve this on our AWS servers we set the local DNS server to resolve Productiondb to the Amazon RDS,  appears to be working